# Поиск ссылок в тексте

Tags: android, java

Допустим, есть текст в `textView1`. Нужно найти в нём ссылки на Интернет-ресурсы и подсветить их.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Берем из textView1 текст
2. Парсим его по заранее заданным шаблонам, может быть "http:// + xxx" или "ххх.ru", "xxx.xxx", "xxx.com"
3. Используем Spannable для подсветки

Пример

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
textView1 .setText("Italic, highlighted, bold.", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

Spannable span = (Spannable)textView1.getText();

span.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 8, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView1 .setText(span);
```